# Variable is dump to database but the data is not updated?

Tags: php

By using var_dump($_POST), I get this:

> array(2) { ["leadershipr"]=> string(1) "2" ["add"]=> string(0) "" } 4

But, data inside the database is not updated.

This is my code for data update,

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{

$id = $_GET['id']; //GET ID

$leadershipr=$_POST['leadershipr'];

$sql = "UPDATE 360feedback SET leadershipr=:leadershipr WHERE id=:id";

$query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(":leadershipr",$leadershipr,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

echo $id;
}
```

Comment: `WHERE id=:id` Where is your bindParam for that parameter

Comment: Obviously this can be regarded as a question caused by a non-reproducible issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you forgot to bind your 'id' parameter?

Maybe add in the following (after the first bindParam and before the execute call):

```
$query->bindParam(":id",$id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```